# How to call an angular method on android webview?

Tags: android, angularjs

I try to call an angular method in java,but it doesn't works.
`webview.loadUrl("javascript:hello()");`
There are javascript and angular in my html,what should I do can call the angular?

Answer (score 1):

first call base url in webview

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("url");
```

Setup Webview client and WebChrome Client. Call your javascript function in Webview client.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {         
           view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(your function)"); // ex. - validation(val1,val2)
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And in WebChrome client you got response from javascript function.

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            Log.e("LogTag", message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I have alreadly did this,but it doesn't works,I think is the js of Angular's problem.